# ckeditor not allow to paste on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

ckeditor not allow user to copy/paste on mobile, below is screenshot. It gives the error "Your browser is does not allow you to paste this way" and user can;t use  `ctrl+v` on mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/595.

Problem should be fixed in version 4.8.1. Until then you can use CKEditor 4.6.2 where paste dialog is still available.

The paste dialog was removed in CKEditor 4.7.0 due to couple of reasons - https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/16954.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't paste in "Paste Dialog" on mobile device (chrome)

Comment: Once you have copied some text and dialog is opened (using toolbar), you simply tap and hold your finger inside the dialog, until paste menu shows. I have just checked and it works perfectly fine in Chrome.

Comment: You can also tap and hold directly in the content of the editor. I don't think that you need any dialog for that.

Comment: Yes you can provide there is content in the editor. If editor is empty, it won't work. I have even tried removing editor menu with `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { enableContextMenu  : false });` but native paste menu doesn't show up in empty editor unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the CKeditor on mobile by adding below code.

This is to check if page is open in mobile

```
function isMobile() {
    try{ document.createEvent("TouchEvent"); return true; }
    catch(e){ return false; }
}
```

and then initiate the Ckeditor if not mobile

```
if(!isMobile()){
   CKEDITOR.replace('note');
}
```

I am using ajax to submit comment and CKeditor need to update the instance before ajax call.

```
if(!isMobile()){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

And this code make the `textarea` blank

```
if(!isMobile())
    CKEDITOR.instances.note.setData('');
else
    $("textarea[name='note']").val('');
```